# Get back to built-in terminal in WebStorm 2021.3

Tags: shell, ide, webstorm

When I open a new terminal window in WebStorm 2021.3, it now opens a full fledged PowerShell floating window instead of the usual built-in terminal.

Any idea on how to get back to the usual behaviour?

Comment: please share a screenshot of **File | Settings | Tools | Terminal** page

Comment: @lena [https://imgur.com/a/8VsrSYh]

Comment: can't reproduce with the same settings.... could you share screenshots that show what it looks like on your end? Is the issue specific to project/shell being used?

Comment: @lena Sure [https://imgur.com/PAYOFvb] As soon as I click on Terminal WebStorm opens a PowerShell window, and the same happens with Bash or Cmd